# How can one meditate?

Tags: meditation

Whenever i try to meditate, my mind wanders in all directions. Random things happen, i feel like that I'm lucid dreaming. I'm just wondering if it is normal to happen or we can control it? Is there any proper way to meditate at one point?

Comment: It is normal for the mind to wander. One way is to follow the mind (as opposed to to forcefully prevent it from wandering) and observe where it goes. This helps. Other than that you can see Vijnana Bhairava Tantra for various places to meditate upon. If that is too complex for you to follow then try some basic stuffs like concentrating on the flame of a lamp/candle or in between the eyebrows etc.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to observe things, that was better. But then i thought that maybe we need to concentrate at one point like you said about concentrating between the eyebrows. When i try to concentrate on the space between the eyebrows, my eyes tend to open.

Comment: I have written an answer. You can also check this lecture - https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_6/Lectures_and_Discourses/Concentration_and_Breathing

Comment: This is not duplicate for me and that's why my answer here does not work there. That is a most generic Q on meditation whereas this is dealing with specific problems related to meditation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meditation is a step by step process and the sadhak (seeker) should start the process with Ashtanga Yoga, the first being Yama and then gradually move on to the next step.

> If you think that closing the eyes and trying to stop the mind is
>   meditation, then you can try it. But you will not be successful unless
>   you have developed very strong willpower. Without the power of
>   anashakti, vairagya or non-attachment, meditation is very difficult to
>   practise. If you are not attached to the experiences of the senses,
>   ego, buddhi (intellect), chitta (memory) and manas (rational mind),
>   then you can experience spontaneous meditation. However, unless and
>   until that happens you will have to work through the practices
>   systematically, stage by stage.

Citing from  Dharana Darshan: Yogic, Tantric and Upanishadic Practices of Concentration and Visualization by Swami Niranjanananda Saraswati:

**Meditative Process**

> Recording to the theory and concept of yoga, meditation X x is a state
>   of mind and consciousness in which there is alertness, dynamism,
>   dissociation of mind and senses, and total concentration. It is
>   definitely not a process to block out events or experiences which are,
>   constantly affecting us. In the Raja Yoga Sutras the process of
>   meditation has been divided into eight stages: (i) yama
>   (self-restraint), niyama (fixed rules), (iii) asana (posture), (iv)
>   pranayama (breath control), (v) pratyahara (sensory withdrawal), (vi)
>   dharana (concentration), (vii) dhyana (meditation) and (viii) samadhi
>   (transcendental consciousness).

**Importance of Concentration in meditation:**

> Concentration is one-pointedness of mind, the ability to hold the
>   awareness of the mind on one point, one place, without wavering. The
>   perfection of concentration leads to meditation. In the state of
>   concentration, the mind is not aware of the external environment or of
>   other peripheral things that surround the object of concentration.

**Ability to concentrate**

> Concentration is spoken of in the Katha Upanishad (2:3:11) where it is
>   explained by Yama, the Lord of Death, to Nachiketas, a young seeker:
>
> The firm control of the senses and the mind is the yoga of
>   concentration. One must be ever watchful for this yoga is difficult to
>   acquire and easy to lose.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an excerpt from the teachings of Sri Ramana Maharshi

> Mr. B. C. Das asked **why the mind cannot be turned inward in spite  of
> repeated attempts**.
>
> M.: It is done by practice and dispassion and that succeeds only
> gradually. The mind, having been so long a cow accustomed to graze
> stealthily on others’ estates, is not easily confined to her stall.
>
> However much her keeper tempts her with luscious grass and fine
> fodder, she refuses the first time; then she takes a bit; but **her
> innate tendency to stray away asserts itself**; and **she slips away**; on
> being repeatedly tempted by the owner, she accustoms  herself to the
> stall; ***finally even if let loose she would not stray  away***.
>
> Similarly
> with the mind. If once it finds its inner happiness it will not wander
> outward.

Answer (score 1):

What I've studied is that all our senses are made in such a way that they process on something external.

Whether it is food, smell, touch, looking some object. Everything is from outside.

Meditation is something we try to sense whenever we sit to meditate.

Additionally, what you are asking, mind is full of thoughts. The basic functionality of brain is to think. No sea is wave less. Brain is like a sea having waves of thoughts. You cannot stop it.

**So you need to focus all your senses inside. The very basic step is to focus on your breath. And keep a watch on your thoughts that how often it drives you away from focusing on your breath. Keep practicing.**